# Limit CPU usage of Xuggler in Java process

Tags: java, cpu, xuggler

I wrote a small application using [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) which combines [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)s into a video (slideshow). The app works fine for smaller images but has problems with higher resolutions like for example 4000 x 6000. CPU usage is at 100% and my machine freezes completely.

Is there a way to limit the process in a way that Java won't use that much CPU?

Comment: Instead, it is better to optimize your program.

Comment: Have you tried something like VisualVM or Yourkit to find the performance bottlenecks?

Comment: Thanks @Bill looks like a excellent point to get started with.